# Word meaning "absorbs everything around him"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe my son. Basically, he sucks in virtually everything around him - music, books, adult conversations, etc - and adds that to his mental image(s) of how the world works.

It's something like absorptive, but that does not feel active enough. Thoughts?

Comment: Can someone explain why the downvote?

Comment: ["Input! More input!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&NR=1&v=Pj-qBUWOYfE), ["MAJOR INPUT!"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AbkbU32X5dI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To describe someone who, for instance, can't get her hands on enough books to read, we often use the adjective *[insatiable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insatiable)* (as in *insatiable reader*).

You might describe your son the same way, either as just *insatiable* or as an *insatiable learner*.

Comment: Thanks, @Hugo! From what I understand, it's an elite club. :)

Comment: insatiable is quite nice... i don't know why i didn't think about that

Answer (score 5):

You might call him *voracious* about observation and learning.

Comment: +1 Though I have come across *voracious* used mostly in relation to reading.

Comment: I've heard people say *"He's in his 'voracious' phase"* (as opposed to his *sullen, withdrawn, insular* phase) of their teenage son. I don't recall anyone ever making this distinction about their daughter's fluctuating behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

While not a single word, the expression *[mind like a sponge](http://thesaurus.com/browse/mind+like+a+sponge)* is often used to describe that concept.

Synonyms: *quick mind, ready grasp, receptivity, quick study*

Comment: Close, but still too passive. Almost more like a bacteria, reaching out and grasping everything around him, growing as a result.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard the word ***consumes*** used to describe this behavior.

Comment: This is much closer - Adjective based on this?

Comment: *consumptive*, but who wants to say that.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: [consumptive genius](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=consumptive+genius&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) is a surprisingly common conjunction.

Answer (score 2):

I would call your son *[perceptive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perceptive)*, but [*attentive*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/attentive) and *[intelligent](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/intelligent)* could also be fitting. He could also be said to have an *inquiring mind*.

Answer (score 2):

You could say he's [receptive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/receptive) - *able or quick to receive knowledge, ideas, etc.: a receptive mind.*

If he's exceptionally so, maybe [hyper-receptive](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hyperreceptive&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) (hyphenated or not). But this can have negative connotations, particularly in medical contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Absorbent?

Here is the definition of *[absorb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absorb)* that I have in mind:

> : to take in and make part of an existent whole

Answer (score 1):

*Assimilative* might be a good word. It means capable of mentally absorbing something. So there is a component of taking it all in, but also fitting new information into your other experiences or world view.

Answer (score -2):

*Black hole*, may it acquire positive connotations, and why not? With a hyphen, if you please, to distinguish from the heavenly non-phenomenon.

Comment: I personally consider them awesome and deserving great respect.

Comment: *My son is [like] a black hole?* You must have some pretty weird neighbours if you can say that without them assuming you mean he's a [bottomless pit](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/bottomless-pit)

Comment: @FumbleFingers "may it acquire positive connotations, and why not?" Those with a fascination for the astronomical do not look down upon anything!

Comment: I too think black holes are fascinating, but putting aside Hawking radiation for the moment, to all intents and purposes what goes in to a black hole never comes out. Seems more like what happens to the contents of my wallet when my son gets too close, rather than a suitable metaphor for his acquisition of knowledge.

Comment: What about infovorous, like carnivorous, but there is no such thing, right?